# use axios.patch with a nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

There's a nested JSON object defined in the server side code of the website that I'm working on, like this:

```js
userinfo:{
   first_name,
   last_name,
   profile:{
      avatar,    //here is the field I need to access!!!
      id,
      some other properties...
   }
}
```

and I want to upload the avatar picture and as you can see, the avatar property is inside a JS object that is itself inside another JS object,

I'd appreciate it if someone help me with these questions:

1. how can I access the `avatar` property
   and
2. how should I write the `axios.patch()` code to upload the avatar file?

Comment: You should have a state, named "data" f.e., then write axios.patch(url, data), that's all

Comment: @Alopwer but I'm sure there must be a better way, cuz the main difference of axios.patch 
 and axios.put is that with "patch" we can send only one field to the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To access nested keys inside a Javascript Object, you can use the `dot (.)` notation. In your case, you can doo something like this

```
// assuming an object with value
const obj = {
  userinfo: {
    first_name: 'first name',
    last_name: 'last name',
    profile:{
      avatar: 'https://some-url',    //field to be accessed
      id: 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
      some other properties...
    }
  }
}

// logging avatar
console.log(obj.userinfo.profile.avatar); // prints "https://some-url"
```

2. Axios Patch is an async function, you can use it like this -

```
axios.patch('https://url-endpoint.co', { 
  avatar: obj.userinfo.profile.avatar
}).then(res => {
  // do something on success
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
  // do something on error
  console.log(err);
});
```

You can read more about axios here - https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases

Answer (score 1):

- Answer for number 1, You can get avatar property in :

> userinfo.profile.avatar

- Answer for number 2, to upload the avatar file use axios you can try this code :

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', userinfo.profile.avatar);

await axios.post('your endpoint url', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }   
})
.then(response => {
  // handle response
  console.log(response);
.catch(error => {
  // handle error
  console.log(error.response);
});
```